# Gnuplot p3md set zrange doesn't work?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to make a map with pm3d, but there are several "white spots" where the z-value exceeds the set zrange. However, when I try to change the zrange scale I see no difference in the plot.

Here's the script I'm using:

```
set term postscript color
set output 'contour.ps'
set size ratio 1
set xrange[-15:25]
set yrange[-15:25]
set zrange[0:200] <------- Changing this range does nothing!
set pm3d map

splot 'format.out' using 2:3:(sqrt($4*$4 + $5*$5 + $6*$6 + $7*$7 + $8*$8 + $9*$9)) with pm3d
```

If I change anything else in the script (say, xrange) I can see the effect in the plot.

Any suggestions?

Also, why is the default zrange set so that some z-values are outside the range? Is there a way to change this default so that it *always* includes all data?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a minimal data set?  You may experiment with `set cbrange` instead of `set zrange`.

Comment: Your solution pretty much worked, see the answer that I posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific case, my data did not have enough space between columns, so when numbers became large the columns started overlapping and numbers became enormous. If, for example columns are defined to be 5 spaces wide, then the data

```
123  987
```

is fine, while the data 12345 and 98765 look like this:

```
1234598765
```

and become joined into a single data point, which gives a number that's outside of any reasonable range. I don't know why gnuplot doesn't warn about two columns being compressed into one...

Also, as mentioned in the comments, changing the cbrange did increase the z range, but of course that didn't help see the several points that were far outside any reasonable range due to the joining of columns.

Comment: This makes sense.  In a text file there is nothing to indicate columns except whitespace, so gnuplot wouldn't assume two columns were merged together; it would just assume there were less columns on that row.

Comment: I suppose it makes sense, but I was a little surprised that gnuplot didn't bark at me for varying the number of columns in my data. I believe Matlab simply wont process something like that.